# <Virtual mouse>An Integer is Required

Tags: python

I'm working on a python script for my Virtual Mouse project using hand Gesture.

I would like to connect a line between centers to each center located on my 3 fingers with sticker color green. But I have this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "multiple.py", line 70, in 
>       cv2.line(frame, (cx1,cy1),(cx2,cy2),(cx3,cy3),(255,0,0),2) TypeError: an integer is required

My Code is here:

```
if(len(conts)==3):
    if(pinchFlag==1):
        pinchFlag=0
        mouse.release(Button.left)
    mouse.release(Button.left)
    x1,y1,w1,h1 = cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
    x2,y2,w2,h2 = cv2.boundingRect(conts[1])
    x3,y3,w3,h3 = cv2.boundingRect(conts[2])

    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x1,y1),(x1+w1,y1+h1),(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x2,y2),(x2+w2,y2+h2),(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x3,y3),(x3+w3,y3+h3),(255,0,0),2)

    cx1 = x1+w1/2
    cy1 = y1+h1/2
    cx2 = x2+w2/2
    cy2 = y2+h2/2
    cx3 = x3+w3/2
    cy3 = y3+h3/2

    #cx = (cx1+cx2)/2
    #cy = (cy1+cy2)/2
    #cz = (cx3+cx1)/2

    cv2.line(frame, (cx1,cy1),(cx2,cy2),(cx3,cy3),(255,0,0),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make the assumption here that you are running this in Python3.

All of these lines:

```
cx1 = x1+w1/2
cy1 = y1+h1/2
cx2 = x2+w2/2
cy2 = y2+h2/2
cx3 = x3+w3/2
cy3 = y3+h3/2
```

Could potentially return `float` objects:

```
>>> 7/2
3.5
>>> isinstance(7/2,float)
True
>>> isinstance(7/2,int)
False
>>> isinstance(7,int)
True
```

Your solution is to turn those `c*` values back into `int`s. Here are a few options:

Integer Division (thanks [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68587/john-kugelman))

```
>>> 7//2
3
```

Ceiling (round up):

```
>>> import math
>>>
>>> math.ceil
<built-in function ceil>
>>> math.ceil(7/2)
4
```

Floor (round down):

```
>>> int(7/2)
>>> 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I'd like to stay the code as is. The problem is, its not running. Am I lacking an integer like (? Thank you. In this area: cv2.line((frame, (cx1,cy1),(cx2,cy2),(cx3,cy3),(255,0,0),2))

Comment: Its not running because you are using `float`s as arguments instead of `int`s. You either have to turn those floats into ints, or use a custom class with your own `.line()` method that accepts floats.